# Counting Roots of Unit

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $p\left(  x\right)  =%
%TCIMACRO{\tprod \limits_{k=1}^{m}}%
%BeginExpansion
{\textstyle\prod\limits_{k=1}^{m}}
%EndExpansion
\left(  x^{e_{k}}-\omega_{k}^{e_{k}}\right)  $ be a polynomial with
$\omega_{k}\in\mathbb{R}$ and $e_{k}\geq2$. Is there any procedure to
determine the vector of exponents $\left(  e_{1},\ldots,e_{m}\right)  $
without knowning any factorization of $p$?

If an order $e_{1}\leq e_{2}\leq\cdots\leq e_{m}$ is stated, I know that there
exists at least a factor $\left(  x^{e_{1}}-\omega_{1}^{e_{1}}\right)  $.

Comment: For uniqueness of such a factorization it's necessary to take $\omega_i \geq 0$ for all $i = 1, \cdots m$. ($x^2-1 = (x-1)(x+1) $)

Comment: Do we know $m$?

Comment: Are you interested if this can be implemented in practice? With what precision do you have the coefficients of p(x)?

Answer (score 1):

A rough idea is to compute $\gcd\left(p(x),p(\xi_n\cdot x)\right)$ for various prime $n$, where $\xi_n$ is a primitive $n$-th power root of unity, which will extract the factors with powers of $x$ divisible by $n$.

For example, $\gcd(p(x),p(-x))$ will give the product of factors with $x$ in even power (assuming that $e_k$ are maximized, e.g., we have $x^6-\omega_1^6$ instead of $(x^3-\omega_1^3)(x^3-(-\omega_1)^3)$). 
Then we replacing $x^2$ with $x$ in the resulting polynomial, and iterate.

If there are no even powers, we try $n=3$ etc.

Comment: Does this work in practice? gcd over the reals is not exact AFAICT, you have rounding errors.

Comment: @joro: If the given polynomial has rational coefficients, one can avoid dealing with real numbers by working with polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ modulo the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(y)$. Here the indeterminate $y$ represents an algebraic counterpart of the primitive $n$-th power root of unity.

Comment: Agree, if it has rational coefficients this is true. But if the coefficients are reals, this appears complicated in practice.

Comment: Not only is it complicated in practice, it is *undecidable* in general.  See the wikipedia on Richardson's theorem.  So, to answer the original post, there is no "procedure" to determine the vector of exponents, because there is not even a procedure to determine whether two real numbers $\alpha,\beta$ are equal. So you could consider the polynomial $f(x):=(x^3-\alpha^3)(x^3-(-\beta)^3)$ and be unable to tell (using a fixed algorithm which is independent of $\alpha,\beta$) whether $f(x)=x^6-\alpha^6$ or not.